# cannot stock images on different media size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create an overlap images on my website with different animation on each image, 768px and 1028px works fine but in 350px the other image 2 are left behind on where it was on 768px, just cant figure out why it didn't move along on 350px

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
@media (min-width: 1028px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 700px) {
```

Thanks in advance,

```css
.image {
  -webkit-animation: spin 5 linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 10s linear infinite;
  position: center center;
  z-index: 1;
  left: px:
}
.under {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.over {
  left: 300px;
  top: 1px;
  z-index: -0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  #slide-4 .content-row {
    min-height: 6em;
  }
  .icon {
    margin-right: 1000px;
  }
  .over {
    min-height: 6em;
  }
  .under {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .over {
    left: 300px;
    top: 1px;
    z-index: -0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1028px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
  #slide-1 .home-row
}
min-height:6em;

}
.icon {
  margin-right: 1000px;
}
.under {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.over {
  left: 300px;
  top: 1px;
  z-index: -0;
}
}
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 700px) {
  #slide-1 .home-row
}
min-height:6em;

}
.icon {
  margin-right:1000px;
}
.under {
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:10px;
  z-index:-1;
}
.over {
  left:300px;
  top:1px;
  z-index:-0;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="slide story" id="slide-1">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="home-row-1">
      <div class="col-12">
        <img class="over" src="images/il1.png" width="300" height="300" />
        <img class="image" src="images/lr1.png" width="300" height="300" />
        <h4 class="animated bounce"><span class="font-thin">No.1 Natural Spring </h4> 
        <h2 class="animated bounceInDown"><span class="font-thin">Mineral water in Europe</h2>
        <h1 class="animated infinite flash"><span class=""font-semibold">Now in Asia.</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <!-- /col-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /row -->
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't really understand your question but your HTMl is invalid which may well be causing the problem. You have extra quotes here:  `<span class=""font-semibold">` and you also never close your spans

Comment: and you have unbalanced `{}` in your css as well, so likely your code is riddled with html+css syntax errors - css syntax errors kill all directives after the spot the error is first detected. check your browser console and you'll likely see those errors being logged.

Comment: Hi Turnip, Thanks for pointing out the span really forget about that.

Comment: thanks Marc B but does not show any error in broswer console. the unbalance {} just my mistake in copy paste the code here. thank anyway

Comment: Hi Turnip, Thanks for pointing out the span really forget about that. my question is, why the images did not stock together when the frame change to 320px, one of the images left behind on the last frame,  but with  frame 1028px and 768px its always stock together were the real images is being showed,